Add short reference to Mathjax Latex Commands
Some new users don't know and not familiar with the $\LaTeX$ syntax. It is perfectly normal but it would be better if we refer them a nice reference that explains the basics.
Also, I suggest that we can add a link to this question in the help page.

Which help page are you talking about in particular?

Also see this and that question.

@SEJPM OMG, how I missed them!  May be in our model?

I fear that we won't get a custom page in that section, because it would have to be branched off and manually curated by the SE dev team. Also at least in theory the edit box hint on the right already tells you that MathJax is available (even though it doesn't refer to further documentation). Maybe this could be a worthwhile change network-wide for all MathJax enabled sites?

@SEJPM I see your point now about SE. It is fixed. The Math.StackExchange has extensive help. CS people always give a link to the meta pages when a new comer made an error.

@SEJPM You are missing this one in the comments. Maybe we should have put that in a different question, or change the question title.

@MaartenBodewes Yes the title should be changed and it should include Mathjax Latex Commands

The math mode can be used for inline in  $...$ as $x^2+x$ and for centered new line $$....$$ as; $$x^2+x$$
MathJax supports essentially the commands native to $\LaTeX$ as well as those defined by amsmath and amssymb (with some exceptions in both directions). For a complete list, see the MathJax reference.
Here some helpful one;

subscripts x_2 $x_2$, if more than one char use braces x_{12} $x_{12}$
supercripts x^2 $x^2$, if more than one char use braces x^{12} $x^{12}$
\operatorname{name} for names of the operators with non-italic and spacesing
\mathbb{Z} for groups, fields as \mathbb{Z_p} $\mathbb{Z_p}$, $\mathbb{F_q}$
\mathcal{O} for calliographic letters, \mathcal{O}, $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ 
align to align the equations; as \begin{align*} A & = B \\ & = C \end{align*} aligned with = $$$$ \begin{align*} A & = B \\ & = C \end{align*} $$$$ 
use \dots for ... 

